What is the general procedure to read and understand a research paper written by a third person?
I am reading a research paper given to me by my supervisor that was published by a research group at another university in another country. The aim is obviously to improve it.
The paper is about constructing energy functions for proteins using machine learning.
As I am reading, I am understanding bits and pieces and struggling to acquire the full picture in my brain. It seems to me that I lack an understanding of some concepts in machine learning and/or protein dynamics.
As I have no time to go to the text books and study everything mentioned in the paper from scratch, what should be the correct approach to reading and comprehending this paper?
Should I take notes and go to my supervisor (a structural chemist of proteins who doesn't have a solid background in ML) to ask for clarifications? Or should I find a machine learning expert and talk to him?
I mean, what do PhD students generally do in this case?

What's your purpose in reading the paper? Do you need to understand it in detail? Consider this answer.

@Anyon, #3. To improve the existing paper to build something on top.

I don't understand why you think that understanding the background of a paper you mean to improve on is somehow an optional task.

@BryanKrause, when did i say that?

You said you had no time to learn the background. You think a couple of questions posed to a professor are going to be enough for you to learn enough biochemistry and machine learning to contribute to research in those fields?

The aim is ‘obviously’ to improve it? Was that explicitly stated? I’ve handed papers to all kinds of folks because I thought they were interesting and they might too, but not with intent that they improve upon them. Get clarity on what is expected of you.

@BryanKrause, coz, if i take time my supervisor becomes impatient and start to scold me. he only wants instant results.

That's a different problem than the one you asked about.

@BryanKrause, that was why I didn't mention it in the first place.

Read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem It's not helpful to ask questions about things that are different than the actual problem you face. The answers won't fix your actual problem, and the question often ends up wasting peoples time trying to figure out what's going on because they are missing important information.

If your actual problem is in fact that your supervisor expects you to produce novel, useful research about a topic that you are unfamiliar with in a timeframe that is unreasonable for becoming familiar with that topic, you will never solve that problem by asking questions about how to become familiar more quickly.

@BryanKrause, That was not my real problem. that was why I didn't ask about that.

It is your real problem, if the reason you can't actually learn about the topic you are doing research on is that your supervisor becomes impatient and only wants instant results. The sooner you realize that the more chance you will have to actually come to a solution.

As for your last question: A smart student in this situation would start looking for a new PhD advisor or/and a PhD program in a different university.

I agree with the comments telling you that your real actual problem is likely to be your advisor.
But, I think the question as posed is also valid, and may be of value to others, too.  When I was a first year PhD, we had a class that might just as well have been titled, "How to be a PhD student," with many guest lectures from the department.  More than one of them talked how they approached understanding a paper-- even tenured professors can't always just leaf through a good paper like it was a novel or a comic book.
And more than once, I found myself mentoring overwhelmed undergrads who were trying to get their feet wet in research, who didn't know how to approach a paper.
This answer is a synthesis of some thing that I do, and some things mentioned in that paper, written for your situation.  They don't necessarily go in order.  They might not all work for you, but I hope at least some do.  But here are some approaches.
Step Zero
Why are you reading this paper?  No, seriously, I see you struggling against this idea in the comments.  Stop struggling!  You need to know!  If it's assigned work from your advisor, ask what you're going to do with it-- is it to improve on the results, as you think?  Is it background?  Is it inspiration?  Is there an application in mind that needs this technique?  Is it the minimum necessary understanding to contribute in that lab?  Is it discussion fodder for the next group meeting?  Is the author coming to visit next week?  Does your advisor think it's nonsense and want to refute it?
These are all valid reasons to read a paper.
Skim The Start And End
Learn the art of skimming a paper.  I usually do this by reading the abstract and intro, then reading lightly through the rest until I get to the conclusions and the discussion.  If I can't follow those two sections, I'm likely to be too lost to read the rest.  But if I do understand the start point and the end point, those will help motivate me to understand the path from one to the other.
Skim The Rest (Again)
You know where the start and endpoints are, now skim so you get a general idea of how those points connect.  You're not trying to memorize the whole map (to use an analogy) but you are trying to get a sense of where the obstacles lie.
Start Reading For Details
Now you can start reading for details.  If you are a new graduate student, you probably won't get too far.  In most labs-- again, if you are just starting out-- that's probably okay.  But make the effort.  The a serious effort.  Keep track of where you get bogged down, make a note to get back to it, and power on.
Fill In The Background
As I said, starting grad students aren't going to get everything in a solid paper, on the first, or even the second read through.  This is where it gets tough, and a lot of these bullet points are dependent on the time pressure, your relationship with your advisor, and so forth.

Look up other research by the authors.  If they are continuing a direct line of research, they may have other details in previous papers.

Ask your advisor, if you have regular meetings.  Be prepared to have at least a few thoughts of your own.

Ask your peers, if this is a group assignment.  Be prepared to try to answer their questions, if they are in the same boat.

Look up simpler papers.  Sometimes these will be helpfully listed in the footnotes of the Introduction.  Sometimes they won't, or those papers won't be helpful.  I would encourage you to cast a wide net, here.  It's not uncommon (at least for me!) to check a half a dozen papers while I'm trying to catch up.  Some would be too advanced.  Some would be at the right level, but not have everything I need.  Sometimes it's just useful to have multiple explanations to compare and contrast.

I really have to hammer this home:  Reading multiple viewpoints of the same material can be really helpful when you're trying to learn something.  It's anecdotal, but I've seen a fair number of colleagues and undergrads think that they should be able to read any given paper-- I think this is one of the ways that impostor syndrome manifests.

Look for tutorial and introduction resources.  In some disciplines, these are easy to find.  Machine Learning is one of them-- sometimes they're published papers, sometimes informal publications, website discussions, even YouTube lectures.  I have no idea what the biology field looks like.

Crack the books.  Not your first resort.  But if you need to be a CS person doing multidisciplinary work in computational biology, well, you're going to need to acquire that knowledge eventually.


None of these are going to be easy or fast.  They are all difficult and time consuming.  That's part of what it means to be a researcher-- you can't teach yourself everything, but you must be able to teach yourself something.  Finding the balance between those is something I believe everyone struggles with.
But this is something your advisor should be helping you with.  And it doesn't seem that he is.

You can treat the problem in a fashion parallel to how good questions are written here on SE. Document what you do and don’t understand, the lengths you have gone to work it out for yourself, how those measures fell short, and what your understanding, hunches, etc. are. Then, take all of that to your supervisor. It shows that you undertook the scholarship that is expected of any PhD-worthy researcher, but it also candidly acknowledges that you are still learning the ropes.
Of course, some advisors can be bears, so you might get your head bitten off. But if you’re happy behaving in a manner that reasonable advisors would consider appropriate, then go for it.
Any advisors worth their salt conceive of their role as not so much to convey content knowledge but to convey how to research.
